# SQL query execution on WP7.1 SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need to develop a function that takes a SQL query as input and execute this in phone database (SQL Server CE) and return result.

As far I know we can query SQL Server CE in wp7.1 only through LINQ. So is it possible to develop that kind of function?

Please help....

Answer (score 0):

you can query SQL Server CE in wp7.1 only through LINQ.